# Angular 9 get component class instance from directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

Before to ask this questions I spent a week here and on official angular docs page trying to find an answer, but no results.

Here is the story. I need to find element on the screen by binded ngModel property and then set focus on it. I CAN'T use @ViewChild since it is inside directive, app is enormously large and it can be apply to any component.

What I have at this point. Interceptor checks API response for marker (for example {row1: "WRONG VALUE"}). Then it passes to behaviorSubject. Directive which applied on top of the app has subscription on this behaviorSubject which triggers function to find element on the screen and set focus on it, but since component maps original property name 'row1' to 'address' (for example) and I kinda stuck at this point. My idea is to get component class instance and find associated/mapped value according original one. Then find it and set focus.

Now the problems:

1. I can't set custom attr with original property name on input because, there can be an array which is rendered thru ngFor loop and already contains mapped/associated property name
2. No @ViewChild, @ViewContainerRef and etc since api can return marker at any point of the app page. App has more than 100+ pages, so it has to be done globally.

What I've tried:

1. Get component class by its selector (couldn't find any good solution besides @ViewChild)
2. Get component by using ng.getComponent() (fails on prod)
3. Get component name from router and then get instance by using injector (fails since directive applied on top, it shows root component and first level children, doesn't show components inside lazy loaded modules).
4. Get component name from route snapshot (fails by the same reason)

So at this point, I'm asking about any idea how to improve logic or how it can be achieved any other method rather than particular answer. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

[Playground stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brt666?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.interceptor.ts)

Comment: If you could provide a stackblitz showing the problem, it would help us to find a solution.

Comment: @ConnorsFan let me try to create one

Comment: @ConnorsFan I provided playground, please take a look

Comment: have you tried using a service to have the component register it's lookup table or whatever you're trying to get from the component?

Comment: @bryan60 I want to get component ref inside directive, in order to find associated (mapped) value. For example api returns sourceItemValue and service passing it to directive, now I want to get orders.component instance, read it and find that sourceItemValue mapped to "amount", if it makes sense

Comment: you're missing more than a few steps there. you'd need some standard method or dictionary relating the 2 values in that component to make use of in the directive, even if you had the reference. at that point, just inject the directive and the component with a shared service, and have the component register it's method or look up table or whatever to be called as needed.

Comment: @bryan60 well, I thought about it. This method might work in small app, but not sure if I'm willing to modify 100+ components to suit my needs

Comment: with your current design, you're in that situation either way. you won't be able to make use of the component ref without some standard method or dict to relate the values, which it sounds like you don't have.

Comment: @bryan60 if you have an idea how it can be done in more efficient way without modifying  100+ components, I can try it, anyway sounds like a dead end here

Comment: you don't have a way of identifying the elements to focus. Getting the component ref doesn't solve that problem. you'll need to put something in place to make that possible. I gave an idea of how to do it.

Comment: @bryan60 now I see what you meant, I finally obtained component reference thru ViewComponentRef and there is no mapped values since it is callback func which converts one value to another.... I'll probably follow your advice and try to create some sort of dictionary for each comp. thanks